# Convert network request from synchronous to asynchronous

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, networking, asihttprequest

I'm currently doing a synchronous network request to load my app which is not the best way as it blocks the UI.  I'm also using ASIHTTPRequest.  I understand I can just change the line from synchronous to asyncronous, but I think I need to setup a block so that I can trigger the table to reload once the async is completed.

The initial ViewController of my app:

```
- (void)fetchAppointmentsForVisibleDate {
    self.appointmentArray = [DrChronoDataSource getTodayData:self.visibleDate];

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:50];
    for (NSDictionary *appointment in self.appointmentArray)
    {
        [array addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", [appointment objectForKey:@"scheduled_time"], [appointment objectForKey:@"patient"]]];
    }
    self.listData = array;
    [self.appointmentTableView reloadData];
}
```

In my app's dataSource class:

```
+ (NSMutableArray*)getTodayData:(NSDate*)today
{
        NSURL *url = myURL here 
        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        [request setPostValue:[dateFormat stringFromDate:today] forKey:@"target_date"];

        [request startSynchronous];

        NSError *error = [request error];
        NSString *responseString;
        if (!error) {
            responseString = [request responseString];
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
        return [responseString JSONValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
+ (void) getTodayData:(NSDate*)today callback:(void (^) (NSError * error, NSMutableArray * array)) callback
{
        NSURL *url = myURL here 
        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        [request setPostValue:[dateFormat stringFromDate:today] forKey:@"target_date"];
        [request setCompletionBlock:^{
            callback(nil, [responseString JSONValue]);
        }];
        [request setFailBlock:^{
           callback([request error], nil);
        ];
        [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)fetchAppointmentsForVisibleDate {
    [DrChronoDataSource getTodayData:self.visibleDate callback:^(NSError *error, NSMutableArray *data))callback {
        if (!error) {
            self.appointmentArray = [data retain];
            NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:50];
            for (NSDictionary *appointment in self.appointmentArray)
            {
                [array addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", [appointment objectForKey:@"scheduled_time"], [appointment objectForKey:@"patient"]]];
            }
            self.listData = array;
            [self.appointmentTableView reloadData];
        }
        else 
            NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
    }];
}
```

You need to change the method so that you will be notified when the download has been completed, using the block. The ASI Completion & Failure blocks need to be set. Please rename them as I have not checked the code and I am sure I have spelt the methods wrong.

Comment: I'm getting syntax error for `+ (void) getTodayData:(NSDate*)today callback:(void (^) (NSError * error, NSMutableArray * array)` saying expected ) and indentifier.

Answer (score 0):

A pattern that I've found works well is to have the backend singleton object parse the response, save it, and send an NSNotification. That way, the relevant view controllers can check update their content only if they are on screen. (Be sure to subscribe and unsubscribe to the relevant notification from within viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear, though).

Comment: What is the benefit of doing this instead of what the other answer has?